# Download file from google drive using python

Tags: python

I am download file from my google drive but, due to network issue. File download is breaking. Is there any way to use python to download file from drive where one can continue from where download crashed?

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25010369/wget-curl-large-file-from-google-drive/39225039#39225039

Comment: @SergeyDyshko I did checked. But, even per the answer the downloading start again right from scratch. I am looking for way to resume download from where it was stopped last.

Comment: Now that you have a downloadable link (my previous comment), you can try something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22894211/how-to-resume-file-download-in-python to save the download progress and resume from the last position. Yet, I haven't seen any software with this kind of feature since 2007 :-)

Comment: @SergeyDyshko youtube-dl have such feature!