# How to reconnect in requests to continue a download

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, tkinter, python-requests

I have been making this download manager app in **tkinter and requests** and I realized that sometimes if the user is downloading multiple files at the same time it fails to keep up and all the downloads end without any error. I also tried urllib3 and the standard urllib though the only difference that urrlib had was that it just raised and error but still failed. I want to make my program in a way that if the download ends:

- Firstly check if the file size is less than it is supposed to be
- If it is then get the size of that file and make a range header like so: {"Range": f"bytes={current_size}-{file_size}"}
- Store the rest of the file in a temp file. After it is downloaded, get the data from both of the files and write it to one (merge the files together)

I used a while loop and temp counter but the problem is that when requests can't keep up and reaches the while loop, it makes millions of temp files with the size of each of them being 197 bytes and it doesn't work. I also tried just using an if loop hoping that it would be fixed, the difference being that it just didn't create millions of files but still didn't work. Finally I tried writing a separate mock program that just straightly got the rest of the files and merged it the half-downloaded file and it worked but for some reason when I try it in my program it doesn't. Keep in mind that I don't want to create a thread for each tempfile because it can be easily written in the same thread as the one that is downloading the file. How can I do this? My code (Be aware that this function is running in a separate thread):

```
currently_downloading = np.array([], dtype='S')
current_temp = 0

def download_files():
    global files_downloading, times_clicked, currently_downloading, packed, last_temp, current_temp
    try:
        abort = False
        win = None
        available_num = 0
        downloaded = 0
        url = str(url_entry.get())
        try:
            headers = requests.head(url, headers={'accept-encoding': ''}).headers
        except ValueError:
            raise InvalidURL()

        try:
            file_size = float(headers['Content-Length'])
        except TypeError:
            raise NotDownloadable()

        name = ""
        formatname = ""

        if num.get() == 1:
            name = url.split("/")[-1].split(".")[0]
        else:
            if name_entry.get().strip() != "":
                for char in str(name_entry.get()):
                    if char in banned_chars:
                        print("Usage of banned characters")
                        raise BannedCharsUsage()
                else:
                    name = str(name_entry.get())
            else:
                raise EmptyName()

        if var.get() == 1:
            formatname = '.' + headers['Content-Type'].split('/')[1]
        else:
            if str(format_entry.get())[0] == '.' and len(format_entry.get()) >= 3:
                formatname = str(format_entry.get())
            else:
                raise InvalidFormat()

        fullname = str(name) + formatname
        path = (str(output_entry.get()) + "/").replace(r" \ ".strip(), "/")
        if chum.get() == 1:
            conn = sqlite3.connect("DEF_PATH.db")
            c = conn.cursor()
            c.execute("SELECT * FROM DIRECTORY_LIST WHERE SELECTED_DEF = 1")
            crnt_default_path = np.array(c.fetchone())
            path = str(crnt_default_path[0] + "/").replace(r" \ ".strip(), "/")
            conn.commit()
            conn.close()
        else:
            pass

        all_files_dir = np.array([], dtype='S')
        for file in os.listdir(path):
            all_files_dir = np.append(all_files_dir, path + file)
        all_files_dir = np.concatenate((all_files_dir, currently_downloading))
        while path + fullname in all_files_dir:
            for element in currently_downloading:
                if element not in all_files_dir:
                    all_files_dir = np.append(all_files_dir, element)
            available_num += 1

            if num.get() == 1:
                name = url.split("/")[-1].split(".")[0] + f" ({available_num})"
            else:
                name = str(name_entry.get()) + f" ({available_num})"
            fullname = name + formatname
            if path + fullname not in all_files_dir:
                currently_downloading = np.append(currently_downloading, path + fullname)
                available_num = 0
                break
        else:
            currently_downloading = np.append(currently_downloading, path + fullname)

        def cancel_dl():
            nonlocal abort
            abort = True

        start_time = time.time()
        try:
            r = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=False, stream=True)
            start = last_print = time.time()
            with open(path + fullname, 'wb') as fp:
                for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=4096):
                    if abort:
                        raise AbortException()
                    downloaded += fp.write(chunk)
                    if downloaded > 1000000:
                        lbl_crnt_size.config(text=f"Downloaded: {round(downloaded / 1000000, 2)} MB")
                    else:
                        lbl_crnt_size.config(text=f"Downloaded: {round(downloaded / 1000, 2)} KB")
                    pct_done = int(downloaded / file_size * 100)
                    lbl_percent.config(text=f"{round(pct_done, 2)} %")
                    download_prg["value"] = pct_done
                    now = time.time()
                    if now - last_print >= 1:
                        speed_sec = round(downloaded / (now - start))
                        if speed_sec > 1000000:
                            lbl_speed.config(text=f"{round(speed_sec / 1000000, 3)} MB/s")
                        else:
                            lbl_speed.config(text=f"{round(speed_sec / 1000, 3)} KB/s")
                        last_print = time.time()
            while os.stat(path + fullname).st_size < file_size:
                current_temp += 1
                rng = {"Range": f"bytes={os.stat(path + fullname).st_size}-{file_size}"}
                r = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=False, stream=True, headers=rng)
                start = last_print = time.time()
                with open(f"temp/Temp-{current_temp}{formatname}", 'wb') as fp:
                    for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=4096):
                        if abort:
                            raise AbortException()
                        downloaded += fp.write(chunk)
                        if downloaded > 1000000:
                            lbl_crnt_size.config(text=f"Downloaded: {round(downloaded / 1000000, 2)} MB")
                        else:
                            lbl_crnt_size.config(text=f"Downloaded: {round(downloaded / 1000, 2)} KB")
                        pct_done = int(downloaded / file_size * 100)
                        lbl_percent.config(text=f"{round(pct_done, 2)} %")
                        download_prg["value"] = pct_done
                        now = time.time()
                        if now - last_print >= 1:
                            speed_sec = round(downloaded / (now - start))
                            if speed_sec > 1000000:
                                lbl_speed.config(text=f"{round(speed_sec / 1000000, 3)} MB/s")
                            else:
                                lbl_speed.config(text=f"{round(speed_sec / 1000, 3)} KB/s")
                            last_print = time.time()
                with open(f"temp/Temp-{current_temp}{formatname}", 'rb') as fp:
                    temp_binary = fp.read()
                with open(path + fullname, 'rb') as fp:
                    main_binary = fp.read()
                with open(path + fullname, 'wb') as fp:
                    fp.write(main_binary + temp_binary)

        except AbortException:
            if os.path.exists(path + fullname):
                os.remove(path + fullname)
```

Comment: Instead of allowing so many downloads that the connections fail, would it not be easier to just have a queue of downloads, and download them one (or two, or three) at a time?

Comment: @joedeandev, Well I wanted the program to be like google chrome, so that you can download files at the same time but that is not the only problem because I realized that if the user's internet connection is not fast it still fails and what if the user's internet connection cuts out? I need to think of these protocols.

Comment: @OmidKetabollahi Why don't you do something like adding the downloaded content to a temporary cache folder? So even if the download fails, the downloading data will still be saved in that folder, and when the user reconnects, you can check for cached files in the folder, and then continue?

Comment: This already has an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22894211/how-to-resume-file-download-in-python

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to resume file download in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22894211/how-to-resume-file-download-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no inbuilt function to do that so you will have to Manually do that .

First thing you need to do is keep record of how many chunks/buffers you have written to file.

**Before** download function declare some variable, say x=0.   (To count how much data is written to file)

then inside the download function check if x == 0.
If true then download normally,
Else : resume download using range header

> **Read Following examples for range header :-** [source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22894873/14976549)

If the web server supports the range request then you can add the Range header to your request:

```
    Range: bytes=StartPos-StopPos
```

You will receive the part between StartPos and StopPos. If dont know the StopPos just use:

```
    Range: bytes=StartPos-
```

So your code would be:

```
    def resume_download(fileurl, resume_byte_position):
        resume_header = {'Range': 'bytes=%d-' % resume_byte_position}
        return requests.get(fileurl, headers=resume_header, stream=True,  verify=False, allow_redirects=True)
```

Another example :-
https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/python-cookbook/0596001673/ch11s06.html

Also update the variable x after writing each chunk (x = x + chunk_size)

And in the end of your download part, add a "if" statement to check if the file size of downloaded file is same as the file size of file on server (you can get that by requests.header.get('Content-Length'). If file size is not same then you call your download function again.

Comment: @Tashiq Banyal, Is there a way to know if the range header is supported?

Comment: -1 Please give credit to the original answer from where you are copying the answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/22894873/8491642

Comment: @Amit Singh i have already provided original answer link, see properly in that "read following examples for range header (source)" line in answer.

Comment: @Omid Ketabollahi do like
 
`response = requests.get(url_here)`

`if response.headers.get("Accept-Ranges") == "none" :`
``` print('Range header not supported !')````
`else :`
``` print('Range headr supported')```